# I want to strip off everything but numbers, $, comma(,)

Tags: c#, regex

I want to strip off everything but numbers, $, comma(,).

this only strip letters

```
        string Cadena;
        Cadena = tbpatronpos6.Text;

        Cadena = Regex.Replace(Cadena, "([^0-9]|\\$|,)", "");
        tbpatronpos6.Text = Cadena;
```

Why doesn't my regex work, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you want something like this?

```
[^\\d\\$,]
```

Answer (score 11):

I suspect this is what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string original = @"abc%^&123$\|a,sd";
        string replaced = Regex.Replace(original, @"[^0-9$,]", "");
        Console.WriteLine(replaced); // Prints 123$,
    }
}
```

The problem was your use of the alternation operator, basically - you just want the set negation for *all* of (digits, comma, dollar).

Note that you don't need to escape the dollar within a character group.

Comment: "Note that you don't need to escape the dollar within a character set." - Are you sure this is correct? IIRC it's only the last char within a char set that is considered to be its actual value, and the rest need to be escaped?

Comment: @user551841: Well, the code I've given works for me. It could be a .NET-specific thing, but I can't see why it would print out the $ if that were being interpreted as an anchor.